# C++ - what ways to structure constant data for performance and encapsulation?

Tags: c++, templates, global-variables, structure, constants

For a long time I have written code with a few program-wide constants defined in, say, `constants.h` thusly:

```
const size_t kNumUnits = 4;
const float kAlpha = 0.555;
const double kBeta = 1.2345;
```

The problem with this approach is that this information is often required in the lower levels of the code when allocating fixed memory blocks, or iterating through loops, so either those units have to #include this common `constants.h`, or the relevant values need to be passed in when those functions are called, cluttering up the interface with values that never change at run-time and hurting the compiler's ability to optimise.

Additionally, having all this lower-level code dependent on a top-level definition header for a few constants seems like a bad smell to me. It's too much like *global variables*, even though they are all constant. It makes it difficult to write reusable code because each component that needs to reference one or more constants has to include the common header. This header has to be manually created and maintained when pooling together a bunch of components. Two or more components may use the same constant, but neither can define it themselves because they both must use the same value in each program (even if the value differs between programs), so both need to #include this high level header file along with all the other constants it happens to provide - not great for encapsulation. It also means that components cannot be used 'standalone' as they need the header definitions to work, but if they include them in a reusable file then they need to be manually removed when the component is brought into the main project. This leads to the mess of program-specific component header files, that need to be manually modified each time a component is used in a new program, rather than simply taking instruction from the client code.

The other option is to provide the relevant constants at run-time, either via the constructor or another member function. However, processing performance is important to me - I have a bunch of classes that all operate on arrays (buffers) of a *compile-time specified fixed size*. Currently, this size is either taken from a constant in `constants.h`, or passed to the object as a function parameter at run-time. I have been doing some experiments with specifying array sizes as *non-type template parameters* or `const` variables and it would seem that the compiler can produce faster code because loop sizes are fixed at compile time and can be better optimised. These two functions are fast:

```
const size_t N = 128;  // known at compile time
void foo(float * buffer) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    buffer *= 0.5f;
  }
}

template <size_t N>  // specified at compile time
void foo(float * buffer) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    buffer *= 0.5f;
  }
}
```

As opposed to the purely run-time version that can't be so well optimised because N isn't known at compile time:

```
void foo(float * buffer, size_t N) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    buffer *= 0.5f;
  }
}
```

Using *non-type template parameters* to pass this information at compile-time has the same performance result as #including the global constants file with all its `const` definitions, but it is much better encapsulated and allows the specific information (and no more) to be exposed to the component that needs it.

So I'd like to pass in the value of N when the type is declared, but this means all my code becomes templated code (and the moving of code to .hpp files that that entails). And it seems that only integral non-type parameters are permitted so I can't pass float or double constants in this manner. This isn't allowed:

```
template <size_t N, float ALPHA>
void foo(float * buffer) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    buffer[i] *= ALPHA;
  }
}
```

So the question I have is what is the best way to handle this? How do people tend to organise their program-wide constants to reduce coupling, yet still gain the benefits of compile-time specified constants?

EDIT:

Here's something using type to hold constant values, and therefore able to pass them down the layers by use of a template parameter. The constant parameters are defined in the `System` struct, and provided to the lower layers `foo` and `bar` as the same-named `System` template parameter:

At the top level:

```
#include "foo.h"

struct System {
  typedef size_t buffer_size_t;
  typedef double alpha_t;

  static const buffer_size_t buffer_size = 64;
  //  static const alpha_t alpha = 3.1415;  -- not valid C++?
  static alpha_t alpha() { return 3.1415; } -- use a static function instead, hopefully inlined...
};

int main() {
  float data[System::buffer_size] = { /* some data */ };
  foo<System> f;
  f.process(data);
}
```

And in foo.h, in a middle layer:

```
// no need to #include anything from above
#include "bar.h"
template <typename System>
class foo {
public:
  foo() : alpha_(System::alpha()), bar_() {}

  typename System::alpha_t process(float * data) {
    bar_.process(data);
    return alpha_ * 2.0;
  }
private:
  const typename System::alpha_t alpha_;
  bar<System> bar_;
};
```

Then in bar.h at the 'bottom':

```
// no need to #include anything 'above'
template <typename System>
class bar {
public:
  static const typename System::buffer_size_t buffer_size = System::buffer_size;
  bar() {}
  void process(float * data) {
    for (typename System::buffer_size_t i = 0; i < System::buffer_size; ++i) {
      data[i] *= static_cast<float>(System::alpha());  -- hopefully inlined?
    }
  }
};
```

This does have the distinct disadvantage of turning a lot (all?) of my future code into templates that take a "System" parameter, in case they ever need to reference a constant. It's also verbose and difficult to read. But it does remove the dependency on a header file, because foo and bar don't need to know anything about the System structure up front.

Comment: Are you layering your projects? Cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_%28object-oriented_design%29. Lakos is a good reference.

Comment: Any reason for avoiding #defines?

Comment: Are you sure functions like `void foo(float * buffer, size_t N)` aren't getting inlined?

Comment: Anyway, what exactly are your constants being used for that requires use across multiple components?

Comment: Yes, I am layering my projects. I have been experimenting with creating a new type that contains information pertaining to a particular aspect of the system (e.g. global buffer size, and buffer type), and then passing that as a template parameter to each lower layer, where it is then passed onto each component as it is declared. I'll update my question with an example of this.

Comment: @Pubby I'm creating a set of similar but separate programs, each using a lot of the same code but with different constants. For example, in one, the buffer size might be 32, in another 64. In another, a particular coefficient might be 1.234, but 5.432 in another. So at the moment I just change the `constants.h` file for each project, but it does mean all the lower-layer components need to *know* about a top-level file, which seems to be the wrong way around to me. It seems better to me that the upper layers pass down these constants to the lower layers instead, on an as-needed basis.

Comment: @Pubby I wrote some experimental code that compares calling a function that loops through an array based on a parameter N - actually a constant divided by N, and when N is passed in at run-time it is slower than when N is also a constant, or a template parameter, which suggests to me that the division is being calculated at runtime rather than by the compiler. I was running with 'release' optimisations in Xcode (clang).

Comment: @Keith the Lakos "pyramid" is actually what I'm trying to achieve, in a way. At the moment, with a `constants.h` file, everything becomes dependent on this one cornerstone, which seems to me to be at the top of the pyramid (or maybe it's a single layer right at the very bottom?). So that results in layers needing to reach up (to get the constants) when really they ought to not know or care about anything above them except to provide an interface.

Answer (score 0):

A good deal of your description motivates why you need these constants global and used all over in the first place.  I guess I just don't see it as a bad code smell if many modules *genuinely* need this information.  It's obviously important information, so treat it as such.  Hiding it, spreading it out or (agast!) putting it in more than one place, seems like change for the sake of it.  Adding templates etc just seems like additional complexity and overhead.

Some points to consider:

- ensure you are using precompiled headers, and that this `common.h` is in there
- try to include `common.h` only in the implementation files, and only where it is truly needed
- ensure the visibility of these symbols is carefully managed; don't expose the constants in every scope just in case they might be needed

Another thought (inspired by @Keith 's comment above) is that you might want to think about your layering.  For example, if you have several components, each of which should ideally be self-contained, you could have local versions of these constants, which just happen to be initialized from these global constants.  That way you greatly reduce coupling and improve locality/visibility.

For example, the main component could have its own interface:

```
// ProcessWidgets.h
class ProcessWidgets
{
    public:
        static const float kAlphaFactor;
    // ...
};
```

and localised in its implementation:

```
// ProcessWidgets.cpp

#include "Common.h"

static const float ProcessWidgets::kAlphaFactor = ::kAlpha;
```

Then all the code in that component just refers to `ProcessWidgets::kAlphaFactor`.

Comment: Imagine I'm adding my existing components to a new project, that already contains a "Common.h", completely unrelated to the one these components are expecting. Let's say I can't rename or modify it - now I have to go through all my components and change this filename to "MyCommon.h" or somesuch - that doesn't seem quite right to me. Shouldn't these constants be "sent down" to the lower layers on an as-needed basis rather than queried from a global pool at the "top"?

Comment: Sounds like you almost want some kind of 'dependency injection' for C++. But that's starting to sound way too complex. You can actually have a file `common.h` exist in multiple directories, and use path prefixes to refer to the one you want. But really, I think maybe a descriptor class might work better, given what you say above. You could have a class that contains all the constants,  and pass it in to the ctor of the main component (instead of doing this via includes as above).

Comment: Alternatively, do not use the name `common`. As in @gavinb 's example, each constant really represents some specific property and can be seen as part of one interface or another. Even if global constants are used put them in a namespace and a file with a descriptive name and you will not have name clash issues

Comment: If I use a unique filename with a namespace, is there a way to override/redefine global constants or locate a different header file? I suppose a bit of #define macro magic could do the job. Also,  the second part of my problem is that I'm bringing in the reusable code as a source-control external (git submodule), so these components really need to find an overridden version of the definition file, stored outside the submodule, when in the context of a project, but their own one when they are standalone (such as part of the reusable component unit-test suite). Compiler include path maybe...